# Panel edge detection, stop before going out of bounds

Tags: vb.net

I have a panel inside it's parent panel that I allow to move. I want it to stop moving BEFORE it falls out of the parent panel. What is the best way to accomplish this. Also I add the panels dynamically.

UPDATE:
Here is the code that goes into the "MyPanel" Panel. Only difference between "MyPanel" vs "Panel" is I add a border and the ability to move it. The "CoolMove" was from another person's answer I found online. I add a "MyPanel1" to form and then add another "MyPanel2" to that and allow it to move only if it is on the "MyPanel1". So with that, I want "MyPanel2" to stay completely in bounds of "MyPanel1". I'm struggling to get the right code to accomplish this.

```
    Private allowCoolMove As Boolean = False
Private myCoolPoint As New Point
Public Overridable Sub MyPanel_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
    'If panel is ontop of Stock panel, then allow manual moving
    If Me.Parent.Name.StartsWith("S") Then
        allowCoolMove = True
        myCoolPoint = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll
        Me.BringToFront()
    ElseIf Not Me.Parent.Name.Contains("keyR") Then
        DoDragDrop(Me, DragDropEffects.Move)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MyPanel_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    If allowCoolMove = True Then
        Me.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X + e.X - myCoolPoint.X, Me.Location.Y + e.Y - myCoolPoint.Y)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MyPanel_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
    allowCoolMove = False
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Each control has a [`ClientRectangle` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle.aspx) that returns the dimensions of its client area (which, for a panel, is the interior part). There is also a [`DisplayRectangle` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.displayrectangle.aspx), which tells you the *entire* area of the control.

And the `Rectangle` structure has a [`Contains` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0kh3ee9e.aspx) overload that takes another `Rectangle` structure and tells you whether one rectangle is fully contained within the bounds of another rectangle.

You should be able to put those two facts together, now, to come up with code that will solve your problem. Something like:

```
Dim rcParentPanelInterior As Rectangle = parentPanel.ClientRectangle
Dim rcChildPanel          As Rectangle = childPanel.DisplayRectangle

If rcParentPanelInterior.Contains(rcChildPanel)
    ' continue to allow moving
Else
    ' forbid moving
End If
```

Comment: I am having trouble getting this to work. I put it in the MouseMove event (which is where my moving code is) and it just stops it from moving?

Comment: @goomba454 : Please update your question with your new code.